# I am creating a TodoApp using Django3.2 and React js and I got the error: cannot import views

Tags: reactjs, django, python-3.6

I am creating a Todo App using Django 3.2 with python 3.6.8 and react js.

I have installed the djangorestframework and Django-cors-headers. However, I cannot get the App views. I could not do the migration as well.

I got the following error when I try to run the server:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 423, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\mydjango\mydjango\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('todoappApi/', include('todoappApi.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\mydjango\todoappApi\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\mydjango\todoappApi\views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from rest_framework.decorators import todoappApi_view
ImportError: cannot import name 'todoappApi_view'
```

Here is my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse

from rest_framework.decorators import todoappApi_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import TaskSerializer

from .models import Task
# Create your views here.
#The function todoappApiOverview will allow React js to get responses from the API
@todoappApi_view(['GET'])
def todoappApiOverview(request):
    todoappApi_urls = {
        'List':'/task-list/',
        'Detail View':'/task-detail/<str:pk>/',
        'Create':'/task-create/',
        'Update':'/task-update/<str:pk>/',
        'Delete':'/task-delete/<str:pk>/',
        }

    return Response(todoappApi_urls)

#React js will get the data responses using the taskListfollowing functions
@todoappApi_view(['GET'])
def taskList(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@todoappApi_view(['GET'])
def taskDetail(request, pk):
    tasks = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@todoappApi_view(['POST'])
def taskCreate(request):
    serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)

@todoappApi_view(['POST'])
def taskUpdate(request, pk):
    task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = TaskSerializer(instance=task, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)


@todoappApi_view(['DELETE'])
def taskDelete(request, pk):
    task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    task.delete()

    return Response('Item succsesfully delete!')
```

Here is the app urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.todoappApiOverview, name="todoappApi-overview"),
    path('task-list/', views.taskList, name="task-list"),
    path('task-detail/<str:pk>/', views.taskDetail, name="task-detail"),
    path('task-create/', views.taskCreate, name="task-create"),

    path('task-update/<str:pk>/', views.taskUpdate, name="task-update"),
    path('task-delete/<str:pk>/', views.taskDelete, name="task-delete"),
]
```

Here is the app settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'todoappApi.apps.TodoappApiConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]
```

Comment: ```from rest_framework.decorators import todoappApi_view``` remove this line from your views.py, that might be a typo?

Comment: The decorator you are using `todoappApi_view` does not exist in the rest framework package. What is it and why not use `api_view`?

Comment: Okay, that's not a typo then. :D

Comment: todoappApi is the name of the backend app and todoappApi_view is the requested function